# JQuery: For each unique data attribute (dynamic) get array of values

Tags: jquery, arrays, custom-data-attribute

I have an HTML table containing dates and values. The table is db generated on load and so both the number of unique dates and therefore the number of unique "data-day" attributes values are dynamic.

```
<table id="pricehistory">
<tr data-day="1">
   <td>Thu 22/08/13 00:00</td>
   <td>value 1</td>
</tr>
<tr data-day="1">
   <td>Thu 22/08/13 00:00</td>
   <td>value 2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-day="2">
   <td>Sun 13/01/15 00:00</td>
   <td>value 1</td>
</tr>
<tr data-day="3">
   <td>Mon 14/01/15 00:00</td>
   <td>value 1</td>
</tr>
<tr data-day="3">
   <td>Mon 14/01/15 00:00</td>
   <td>value 2</td>
</tr>
<tr data-day="3">
   <td>Mon 14/01/15 00:00</td>
   <td>value 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I already have an array for each of the unique data-day values.

```
var dataAttributes = {};

$("#pricehistory tbody tr").each(function () {
   dataAttributes[$(this).attr('data-day')] = true; 
});

var uniqueDataAttributes = new Array();

for(var i in dataAttributes)
{
   uniqueDataAttributes.push(i);
}

$.each(uniqueDataAttributes, function (i, v) {
   alert(v);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nB3ru/7/

What I'd like to achieve is to get an array of values for each of the unique "data-day" values, so in the above example something along the lines of the following:

```
dd1 ["value 1","value2"]
dd2 ["value 1"]
dd3 ["value 1","value 2","value3"]
```

The idea behind this is that I already know what all of the possible values could be, so be getting an array of each of the values by day I can then compare this to an "allValues" array.

Can anyone assist me with this please?

Adeneo provided the following answer which is great and works perfectly...

```
var dataAttributes = {};

$("#pricehistory tr").each(function (index, el) {
   if ( ! ($(el).data('day') in dataAttributes) ) dataAttributes[$(el).data('day')] = [];
   dataAttributes[$(el).data('day')].push( $(el).find('td:last').text() );
});
```

... however what I should have mentioned on my original post (my apologies) is that I would only like to store the unique values in each of the arrays.

Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change it a little bit

```
var dataAttributes = {};

$("#pricehistory tr").each(function (index, el) {
    if ( ! ($(el).data('day') in dataAttributes) ) dataAttributes[$(el).data('day')] = [];
    dataAttributes[$(el).data('day')].push( $(el).find('td:last').text() );
});
```

and you end up with

```
{
    "1": [
        "value 1",
        "value 2"
    ],
    "2": [
        "value 1"
    ],
    "3": [
        "value 1",
        "value 2",
        "value 3"
    ]
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zqbn983d/)

Comment: This is great. Thanks. Is there a way for this to accomodate duplicates? I.e. only to store the unique values in each of the arays? Thanks again so much!

Comment: @FECoder - Sure, add another `if` statement to see if the value already exists, like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zqbn983d/9/**

Answer (score 0):

If i unterstood you correctly the following code will work for you.

```
var dataAttributes = {};

$("#pricehistory tbody tr").each(function () {
   var $elem = $(this);
   var dd = $elem.attr('data-day');

   // Initializing the unique dd if not already initialized
   dataAttributes[dd] = dataAttributes[dd] || []; 

   // Push the new value to the unique dd array
   dataAttributes[dd].push($elem.find('td:last').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like bellow

```
var object = {dd1:[],dd2:[],dd3:[]}

$.each(uniqueDataAttributes, function (i, v) {
    $('tr[data-day="'+v+'"]').each(function(){
        object["dd"+v].push($(this).children().eq(1).text());
    });
});

console.log(object)
```

The console will print this, (output is stringified)

```
{"dd1":["value 1","value 2"],"dd2":["value 1"],"dd3":["value 1","value 2","value 3"]}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nB3ru/8/)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it requires a pre-existing object to be created, with an unknown number of keys.

Comment: I agree. Thanks so much for your answer all the same, but unique dates and therefore the number of unique "data-day" attributes values are dynamic